# TSQL increment a column and start over based on another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table as follows:

```
colA   colB(unique)   colC
---------------------------------
1      1449           0.50000000
1      1451           1.03400000
1      2404           5.98750000
1      1454           6.00000000
3      1465           1.40000000
3      1467           1.56000000
3      1476           3.00000000
3      1469           4.00000000
3      1490           5.00000000
```

I want to make col C an incremeting whole number (ok to leave scale) that starts over when colA changes, like so:

```
colA  colB (unique)  colC
----------------------------------
1     1449           1.00000000
1     1451           2.00000000
1     2404           3.00000000
1     1454           4.00000000
3     1465           1.00000000
3     1467           2.00000000
3     1476           3.00000000
3     1469           4.00000000
3     1490           5.00000000
```

Any ideas for doing this?  I'm on SQL Server 2008.  This table could get very large. Thank you!

Comment: Does this number have to be calculated and stored? You could just have an identity column for the whole table then use `row_number() over (partition by colA order by id)` to calculate the sequence number of ` colC` in your select queries.

Comment: Will colA ever go back to an earlier value (i.e., could a new row be inserted at the end of the above table with colA of 1)?  If so, how should colC behave?  I can think of at least three ways to handle this problem (what @Martin-Smith said, a view, and a trigger), depending what your needs actually are.

Comment: Andrew-- Yes. The above tables are just the result of an order by.

Comment: Martin-- The second table is a table we store and refer to often.  colC is actually a sort column.  The first table is calculated from several other tables once per month and then we update the second table.  Unfortunately, we need colC to be an integer for other reasons.  Thank you for the answer. I'm not too experienced with views, but I'll do some research on your answer.  Also thanks to whomever formatted the question.  This is my first time to use SO. I'm quite impressed!

Comment: @John: <cough> **My** answer <cough> :)  A view is just a prepared SQL statement--think of it like a macro.  I'm referring to non-indexed/non-materialized views...

Comment: Martin-- Thank you so much! row_number() over (partition by colA order by colC) worked like a charm!  Guess I need to look at using views instead of storing ranked values now :). Thanks again.

Comment: OMG- Thank you. I understand your answer now... and thank you for re-formatting my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wouldn't store ranked values--they need to be maintained.  I'd usually use a view for things like this:

```
CREATE VIEW your_view AS
  SELECT t.cola,
         t.colb,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t.cola
                               ORDER BY t.colc) AS colc
    FROM YOUR_TABLE t
```

But you can use a WITH statement in an UPDATE:

```
WITH summary AS (
  SELECT t.cola,
         t.colb,
         t.colc,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t.cola
                               ORDER BY t.colc) AS cold
    FROM YOUR_TABLE t)
UPDATE summary
   SET colc = cold
```